# Notification Library for Windows

Tags: python, windows, notifications

I'm developing a small tray-icon application for Windows and I need to display non-intrusive visual notifications similar to those that appear when you receive a new message in MSN Messenger or any other IM application.

I have looked at [Snarl](http://www.fullphat.net/index.php), but it seems to be a separate application that I need to install. I want something that could be bundled with my application in one installer, a library.

Which one do you recommend?

Python support is a huge plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by depending on a GUI library.

For example, with PyQt,it is possible :

- [PyQt QSystemTrayIcon Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsystemtrayicon.html)
- [QSystemTrayIcon Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html)
- [Example of QSystemTrayIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html) (in C++, easy to adapt to python)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one for .NET for the Genghis project ([link here](http://www.codeplex.com/genghis)) a while back.  Looks like it is over at MS CodePlex now.  Look for the "AniForm" class.  [Here](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/genghis/screenshots/AniForm.JPG) is a screenshot.

It has more of an older MSN Messenger look and feel but should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Are you developing the application in Python? It depends what GUI toolkit you're using.

If you're using wxPython, you could try [ToasterBox](http://xoomer.alice.it/infinity77/main/ToasterBox.html), or the wxPopupWindow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anyhting.
Just use toasters windows with Win32 api