# Do you know which library Firefox 3 uses for the "download completed" info?

Tags: c++, popup, notifications, firefox-3

It's the window that shows up when you set showAlertOnComplete = true.

```
about:config
browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete = true
```

I want to add notification messages in my applications and I need to find a good open source library for that task.

Comment: On linux, "libnotify" is pretty much standard i heard: http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing notifications.
In terms of open source libraries, there are a number of system-wide notification schemes, such as [Snarl](http://www.fullphat.net/index.php) (Windows), [Growl](http://growl.info/) (Mac) or [Mumbles](http://www.mumbles-project.org/) (Linux).

If you to work only with what is already on the platform, there are some related questions on SO around the Windows API for notifications:

- [Notification Library for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344442/notification-library-for-windows)
- [Notification API for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177/notification-api-for-windows)
- ["Speech bubble" notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593341/speech-bubble-notifications)