# running python file in windows services

Tags: python, windows-services

I have a python file that will synchronize my MySql Database from my own server to the local server. I want to install it as a windows services every time my local server boot up. Can you help me? I want to add also that can I make a GUI for that services just like an Apache that will display beside the task bar clock? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service is nothing but a process/program that run on regular interval checks and runs accordingly.

If you have script already written, then another script,**service_script** which will do the following

- It should check if the program is required to run ? (Syn is required
  if two parties are not in same state)
- At what interval you should check, there is a chance that this script is required to
  run. Say you DB updated every 10 mintues. Then code you script to syn
  with it. If job is there do it else set it to sleep.
- If possible make sure your script is optimised, following standards &
  all basic things.

As for GUI, you store these success/failure details in a Log file. If you want GUI - a small php interface/python simple http will help you set up a interface.

I have some experience in doing some monitoring scipts & dashboard, but not quiet simmilar to your work.

Godspeed.

Comment: A windows service is a very specific thing

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with the frst Question:

> it as a windows services every time my local server boot up

Windows 7:

1. RightClick on Computer
2. LeftClick "Manage"
3. In the "System" tab there is something like a planner for tasks. You can use this one to start a local file at boot and before LogIn.

If you do need it after LogIn then you can put the script in the startup folder in the start menu.

google: python icon notification area windows
[Notification Library for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344442/notification-library-for-windows)